# Есть ли в intellij idea такой же удобный конструктор XML?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В NetBeans имеется удобный конструктор xml файла настройки (например `web.xml`). И не нужно запоминать 100500 тегов например `<mapping>`, `<redirect>` и так далее. Есть ли такой в IDEA или Eclipse или все же придется учить эти теги?

Comment: В обоих случаях из коробки всё есть.  Для Eclipse довесков и рюшечек навалом: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/xml И для идеи тоже найдётся: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/index?pr=idea&search=xml

Comment: Поверьте, в IDEA 99% функционала удобнее, чем в NetBeans. А еще есть куча того, чего нет ни в NetBeans, ни в Eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создайте проект в Idea, выберите дефолтный xml-файл, который был создан в новом проекте, и вам откроется "удобный конструктор XML".

Answer (score 2):

Есть, конечно, там специальная кнопочка "дизайн" в левом нижнем углу(под кодом)...Хотя знать теги все-равно знать надо, но со временем выучится:)